# How to make sure only one instance of a Bash script is running at a time?

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I want to make a sh script that will only run at most once at any point.

Say, if I exec the script then I go to exec the script again, how do I make it so that if the first exec of the script is still working the second one will fail with an error. I.e. I need to check if the script is running elsewhere before doing anything. How would I go about doing this??

The script I have runs a long running process (i.e. runs forever). I wanted to use something like cron to call the script every 15mins so in case the process fails, it will be restarted by the next cron run script.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want a pid file, maybe something like this:

```
pidfile=/path/to/pidfile
if [ -f "$pidfile" ] && kill -0 `cat $pidfile` 2>/dev/null; then
    echo still running
    exit 1
fi  
echo $$ > $pidfile
```

Comment: If you mean on the kill command, the -0 indicates that the process is still running but does not touch it if it is.  The 2>/dev/null will discard any unwanted noise in case the process is in fact not running.

Comment: I have read that PID files are not a good way to solve this problem... Given that some process can take the same PID etc..?

Comment: It is possible for a process ID to be reused, this is true.  If you're really worried about this, you might use the flock(1) program by Peter Anvin, which ships with the util-linux distribution.

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to use lockfile command. See [using lockfiles in shell scripts (BASH)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120312131841/http://www.madmadmod.com/programming/31-lockfile-conditional-semaphore-file-creator.html) or http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html.

The second article uses "hand-made lock file" and shows how to catch script termination & releasing the lock; although using `lockfile -l <timeout seconds>` will probably be a good enough alternative for most cases.

Example of usage without timeout:

```
lockfile script.lock
<do some stuff>
rm -f script.lock
```

Will ensure that any second script started during this one will wait indefinitely for the file to be removed before proceeding.

If we know that the script should not run more than X seconds, and the `script.lock` is still there, that probably means previous instance of the script was killed before it removed `script.lock`. In that case we can tell `lockfile` to force re-create the lock after a timeout (X = 10 below):

```
lockfile -l 10 /tmp/mylockfile
<do some stuff>
rm -f /tmp/mylockfile
```

Since `lockfile` can create multiple lock files, there is a parameter to guide it how long it should wait before retrying to acquire the next file it needs (`-<sleep before retry, seconds>` and `-r <number of retries>`). There is also a parameter `-s <suspend seconds>` for wait time when the lock has been removed by force (which kind of complements the timeout used to wait before force-breaking the lock).

Comment: Great link, I swear by "set -x" and "set -e".

Comment: Interesting, never tried this before. Thanks!! Dumb question... I'm assuming if the process holding the lock is killed/dies the lock is released without any need for hacking etc..?

Comment: Looks like the lock file will remain in such case. However, there is a parameter (-s XX) to specify a timeout after which lock is removed regardless if the process does it or not.

Comment: Ok, parameter may be wrong. On my box it is -l. Using timeout I guess is a question of design - whether your script/process can process errors and not die unexpectedly, or not. You could also have another process watching you main process and manage lock files. =)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18981146)

Comment: @Bidou My bad, updated the answer (and replaced the dead link with Web Archive one)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `run-one` package, which provides `run-one`, `run-this-one` and `keep-one-running`.

The package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/run-one

The blog introducing it: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/02/introducing-run-one-and-run-this-one.html

Answer (score 2):

Write the process id into a file and then when a new instance starts, check the file to see if the old instance is still running.

Comment: Just checking if the pid is valid can be error-prone because there could be an unrelated process that is running with that pid.  Using `ps` to check if the process is actually related can get messy.  What if two instances of the same script could be running, but with different arguments?

Comment: It's definitely not foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

```
(
        if flock -n 9
        then
                echo 'Not doing the critical operation (lock present).'
                exit;
        fi

        # critical section goes here

) 9>'/run/lock/some_lock_file'
rm -f '/run/lock/some_lock_file'
```

From example in flock(1) man page. Very practical for using in shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a tool that does this:
https://github.com/ORESoftware/quicklock

writing a good one takes about 15 loc, so not something you want to include in every shell script.

basically works like this:

```
$ ql_acquire_lock
```

the above calls this bash function:

```
function ql_acquire_lock {
  set -e;
  name="${1:-$PWD}"  # the lock name is the first argument, if that is empty, then set the lockname to $PWD
  mkdir -p "$HOME/.quicklock/locks"
  fle=$(echo "${name}" | tr "/" _)
  qln="$HOME/.quicklock/locks/${fle}.lock"
  mkdir "${qln}" &> /dev/null || { echo "${ql_magenta}quicklock: could not acquire lock with name '${qln}'${ql_no_color}."; exit 1; }
  export quicklock_name="${qln}";  # export the var *only if* above mkdir command succeeds
  trap on_ql_trap EXIT;
}
```

when the script exits, it automatically releases the lock using trap

```
function on_ql_trap {
   echo "quicklock: process with pid $$ was trapped.";
   ql_release_lock
}
```

to manually release the lock at will, use `ql_release_lock`:

```
function ql_maybe_fail {
  if [[ "$1" == "true" ]]; then
      echo -e "${ql_magenta}quicklock: exiting with 1 since fail flag was set for your 'ql_release_lock' command.${ql_no_color}"
      exit 1;
  fi
}

function ql_release_lock () {

   if [[ -z "${quicklock_name}" ]]; then
     echo -e "quicklock: no lockname was defined. (\$quicklock_name was not set).";
     ql_maybe_fail "$1";
     return 0;
   fi

   if [[ "$HOME" == "${quicklock_name}" ]]; then
     echo -e "quicklock: dangerous value set for \$quicklock_name variable..was equal to user home directory, not good.";
     ql_maybe_fail "$1"
     return 0;
   fi

   rm -r "${quicklock_name}" &> /dev/null &&
   { echo -e "quicklock: lock with name '${quicklock_name}' was released.";  } ||
   { echo -e "quicklock: no lock existed for lockname '${quicklock_name}'."; ql_maybe_fail "$1"; }
   trap - EXIT  # clear/unset trap

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `flock`, but in a different way than suggested by @Josef Kufner. I think this is quite easy and `flock` should be available on most systems by default:

```
flock -n lockfile myscript.sh
```