# While Loop in PHP, inside a shell script

Tags: php, linux, shell, ubuntu

If I have a PHP script written in PHP file that has a while loop, I make a shell script (say `test.sh`) and tell the shell script to run the php file.

Now If I do `sh test.sh` within a Linux terminal on an EC2 instance, and I close the terminal, does the php script keep on running? (remember I have a while loop inside the PHP file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No start the script in a screen.

install the screen programm. Then you can start your script with `&`

`sh test.sh &`

then your script is running in background.

**Edit:** Answer only run a cron/script once

[Bash Script run only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482602/bash-script-run-only-once)

Comment: I can assume it as a background service like cron then right?

Comment: Then the service is running in background until the script is finished. When you have a cron you don't need screen when you start your script with a cron its running until its finished. When you execute it over a terminal its clonsed if the session is closed.

Comment: how can I make a cron to run only once

Comment: No I just want the Cron job to run once instead of daily,monthly,hourly issues

Comment: Then put the time of the cron to the exact day.